# How do I create a matplotlib slideshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cross-platform, slideshow

The Python/pyplot code below generates four figures and four windows. I need code that opens one window showing fig1. Then when the user presses right arrow button or right arrow key the same window clears fig1 and shows fig2. So basically only one of the four figures will be selected by the user for viewing in a slideshow. I have searched for an answer in the docs and online without success. I have edited the question to show the definition of six axes that appear in the four figures. It appears that one must associate the axes with a single figure and then draw, clear, and redraw axes to simulate a slideshow in the default GUI?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(3, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(3, 1, 2, sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig1.add_subplot(3, 1, 3, sharex=ax1)
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax4 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
fig3 = plt.figure()
ax5 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
fig4 = plt.figure()
ax6 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.show()
```

Ideally I would like to set the backend to ensure the same code functions on MacOS, Linux, and Windows. However I would be satisfied to get a very basic slideshow working on Windows 7 and develop for other OS later if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:
(click on the graph to switch)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

i = 0

def fig1(fig):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))


def fig2(fig):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x, np.cos(x))


def fig3(fig):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x, np.tan(x))


def fig4(fig):
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
    ax1.plot(x, np.sin(x))
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
    ax2.plot(x, np.cos(x))
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
    ax3.plot(x, np.tan(x))

switch_figs = {
    0: fig1,
    1: fig2,
    2: fig3,
    3: fig4
}

def onclick1(fig):
    global i
    print(i)
    fig.clear()
    i += 1
    i %= 4
    switch_figs[i](fig)
    plt.draw()

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
fig = plt.figure()
switch_figs[0](fig)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: onclick1(fig))

plt.show()
```

Comment: This solves my problem nicely! I accepted this answer b/c it works in Windows 7 default GUI supporting full screen and resizing. It works even when I use fig.set_tight_layout(True) inside each def statement. But if I define a figure size 10 x 6.5 inches at 100 dpi there is a problem redrawing the figure at full size. I will write separate code for print support.